# Possible in Editor (DevDemon) to place image without p-tags around it?

Tags: devdemon, editor

I don't want the default p-tags added to my images when adding them in Editor.

The HTML should look like this:

```
<p>
    text
</p>
<img src="#" />
<img scr="#" />
<p>
    text
</p>
<img src="#" />
```

etc.

If I add pictures now it adds paragraph-tags around the images automatically.

PS. I can save it the right way one time (in code-mode), but it changes back when I edit the post (even if I don't change anything).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an add-on such as Hacksaw: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hacksaw to strip out any unwanted paragraph tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is something the WYSIWYG editor should solve. You could for instance wrap them in a div (which by default has no css styling and margins etc.). The WYSIWYG usually has a formatting or block-level select menu for changing and/or setting the element.

Seems DevDemon-editor is based on redactor, Wygwam is based on CKeditor